# Transparent with shading effect in a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have a textView in my layout I want it to show whats behind it but still with a shading effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This shadow in textView and also set background Transparent.

```
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:shadowRadius="2"  android:shadowColor="#0000ff"
              android:shadowDx="2"
              android:shadowDy="4" android:id="@+id/EditText01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: hey thxx it works :) can u explain a bit what is shadowDx/dy and shawdowRadius

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:shadowDx